# Minimum Database Permissions for EF Code First DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

We are using EF4.3 and Code First.

Our DBAs are keen to reduce the permissions developers have on the development database. But we've had many situations where we've been unable to create the database after it's been dropped when we call `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`

What are the minimum database permissions required for a user to be able to call both `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` and `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`?

Do these require different permissions?

Is there any documentation that I can refer our DBA's to that will help explain what is required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both initializers need permissions for dropping and creating database. These operations require very different permissions:

- Database can be dropped by its owner - this permission is localized to the database (`db_owner` in SQL Server).
- Database can be created only by the user with global server permission to create database - that is usually permission provided only to highly privileged users (`dbcreator` role in SQL Server)

You also need read access on Master database.

Btw. if this is related to development environment you should use your own local database server instead.

Comment: +1 for your actual answer, but it should start with "No", because it's the same for `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` and `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`: both require both drop and create permission.

Comment: @hvd: You are right - I transformed the question to *"What permissions are needed to drop and create database?"* I'm going to edit my answer.